# How to find all paths from a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm new to neo4j, i've read a couple of tutorials but i am stuck with finding all paths from a node till it reaches another when the status changes and different path each time.

I've made a picture:
[image: https://imgur.com/B0q4SM0]

Starting from the node at the top, I would like to find all nodes T that have status=1 and we move from node of type O to T with a 'o' relationship and from T to O with 'i' relationships. If we reach a node T with status = 0 then we go the 'i' relationship and check if T status = 1 etc

I don't know the depth of the graph. I've found on the manual that we can use [r*1..] but i am not sure how to use here.

I have tried

```
match (o1:O)-[:o]-(t:T), (t)-[:i]-(o2:O)-[:o]-(t2:T) 
return o1, t, o2, t2
```

for the first depth but i don't know how to do it with unknown depth and make go deeper as long as status is not 1

Comment: Until you find out how to extend the query, it would really help to put arrows on your relationships; i.e. `MATCH (o1:O)-[:o]->(t:T)`, because Neo4j can leverage the direction to speed up the query.

Comment: In your diagram, not all `T` nodes have a status. By "starting at the top", do you mean the single node at the top of your diagram? And are you traversing relationships in a backwards direction? Can you show what the expected result is supposed to be based on your diagram?

Answer (score 0):

Your schema looks like so (the question mark means I'm not sure what relationship you wanted there).
(:O)<-[:o]-(:T)<-[:i]-(:O)<-[:o]-(:T)<-[:?]-(:T)

You need to somehow identify the first node from which you start, and I'm not sure exactly what nodes you are trying to get from the schema, but something like this would return all nodes with status 1 that are somehow connected to first node, which here is just identified by having status 0 (so might actually be more than one node).

```
MATCH (firstnode:O {Status: 0})<-[:o|:i*..]-(othernodes) WHERE othernodes.Status=1 RETURN othernodes
```

But be warned - any *.. command will take forever to run.